# Configurable product swatches not displayed crossed out when out of stock in Magento 2.4.5-p1

Tags: magento2.4.5

Configurable product swatches not displayed crossed out when out of stock after upgrade Magento 2.4.5-p1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am in Magento 2.4.5-p1

Searching y found a solution. It final fix will be released in Magento 2.4.6

But for now i try this solution, and work for me:

[image]

Original post:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/35319#issuecomment-1111842395

Comment out the original lines in vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Helper/Data.php (lines 93 - 119) and add these lines:

```
public function getOptions($currentProduct, $allowedProducts)
    {
        $options = [];
        $allowAttributes = $this->getAllowAttributes($currentProduct);
        foreach ($allowedProducts as $product) {
            $productId = $product->getId();
            foreach ($allowAttributes as $attribute) {
                $productAttribute = $attribute->getProductAttribute();
                $productAttributeId = $productAttribute->getId();
                $attributeValue = $product->getData($productAttribute->getAttributeCode());
                if ($product->isSalable()) {
                    $options[$productAttributeId][$attributeValue][] = $productId;
                }
                $options['index'][$productId][$productAttributeId] = $attributeValue;
            }
        }
        return $options;
    }
```

Then run commands:

```
composer update 
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy es_CO en_US (your local...)
```

and run file permissions

:) Good Coding

Answer (score 0):

Check your custom theme.
In the last update the json handling the swatches are notyceable different. There are a new attribute called something like "saleable", and this is the array with the in stock products.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have tried with the default Luma theme but issue is still.
This issue facing after the upgrade. 2.4.4 to 2.4.5-p1

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer did not work for me, but after scrolling through the linked Magento GitHub issue, I found a solution, which involved modifying the swatch-renderer.js

https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/1fe7184e67ca089294787cd45c98c44cb0b13bac

I copied the swatch-renderer.js file into app/design/Vendor/theme/Magento_Swatches/web/js/swatch-renderer.js, and added the following code:

```
At line 501:

    disableSwatchForOutOfStockProducts: function () {
        let $widget = this, container = this.element;

        $.each(this.options.jsonConfig.attributes, function () {
            let item = this;

            if ($widget.options.jsonConfig.canDisplayShowOutOfStockStatus) {
                let salableProducts = $widget.options.jsonConfig.salable[item.id],
                    swatchOptions = container.find('.swatch-option');

                swatchOptions.each(function (key, value) {
                    let optionId = $(value).data('option-id');

                    if (!salableProducts.hasOwnProperty(optionId)) {
                        $(value).attr('disabled', true).addClass('disabled');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    },

At line 912, in the _Rewind function

    this.disableSwatchForOutOfStockProducts();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having this bug on 2.4.5p1. I implemented the swatch_renderer.js solution from cjochum above which fixed my problem on single-swatch products, but broke two-swatch products (color and size). I fixed this by wrapping in a conditional:

```
            disableSwatchForOutOfStockProducts: function () {
                let swatchOptArr = document.getElementsByClassName('swatch-attribute');
                let pdpCheck = document.getElementsByClassName('catalog-product-view');
              
                if (swatchOptArr.length <= 1 && pdpCheck.length >= 1) {
                    let $widget = this, container = this.element;

                    $.each(this.options.jsonConfig.attributes, function () {
                        let item = this;

                        if ($widget.options.jsonConfig.canDisplayShowOutOfStockStatus) {
                            let salableProducts = $widget.options.jsonConfig.salable[item.id],
                                swatchOptions = container.find('.swatch-option');

                            swatchOptions.each(function (key, value) {
                                let optionId = $(value).data('option-id');

                                if (!salableProducts.hasOwnProperty(optionId)) {
                                    $(value).attr('disabled', true).addClass('disabled');
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
```

Then calling `this.disableSwatchForOutOfStockProducts();` at the very end of `_Rewind()` to run the function